# jq: assign property from parent element

Tags: json, jq

I just seem to have a hard time figuring out the mindset of `jq` for more than simple extraction problems, but hopefully I can keep growing my skills...

I have data that looks like this synthetic example:

```json
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "attrs": {
        "name": "One"
      },
      "vaults": [
        {
          "attrs": {"name": "Private", "type": "P"},
          "items": [
            {
              "foo": "001",
              "overview": {"subtitle": "foo"}
            },
            {
              "foo": "002",
              "overview": {"subtitle": "foo", "tags": ["a tag"]}
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "attrs": {"name": "Public", "type": "P"},
          "items": [
            {
              "foo": "001",
              "overview": {"subtitle": "foo"}
            },
            {
              "foo": "002",
              "overview": {"subtitle": "foo", "tags": ["a tag"]}
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

For every record in `.accounts[].vaults[].items[]`, I need to create/replace its `overview.tags` value with `[.Parent.Parent.attrs.name]`, if `.Parent` were to get the current element's parent in the tree.

So the desired output would be this:

```json
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "attrs": {
        "name": "One"
      },
      "vaults": [
        {
          "attrs": {"name": "Private", "type": "P"},
          "items": [
            {
              "foo": "001",
              "overview": {"subtitle": "foo", "tags": ["Private"]}
            },
            {
              "foo": "002",
              "overview": {"subtitle": "foo", "tags": ["Private"]}
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "attrs": {"name": "Public", "type": "P"},
          "items": [
            {
              "foo": "001",
              "overview": {"subtitle": "foo", "tags": ["Public"]}
            },
            {
              "foo": "002",
              "overview": {"subtitle": "foo", "tags": ["Public"]}
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a nice way in `jq` to achieve this?

Background: this is the format of [1Password](https://1password.com/)'s `.1pux` export data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is using update-assignment `|=`

```
jq '.accounts[].vaults |= map(.items[].overview.tags = [.attrs.name])'
```